# zxing.net.mobile in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to decode PDF417 codes from a video stream.

I have successfully accomplished it by crating a UWP that uses Zxing.net.mobile, but there is a problem. I have to generate a .exe file for the final user (can't be done in UWP), the user does not want to go to MS Store to download it or have to enable developer mode to install it using powershell.

So, UWP is not a very good option.

I tried using pyzbar and opencv and it succesfully decodes QR codes from a video stream, but fails to decode PDF417 codes.

I also tried using python-zxing which is able to decode a PDF417 image successfully but the problem comes when trying to decode from a video stream (it gets super, super, ultra slow).

So, now a question came to my mind. Is something like Zxing.net.mobile available in python?

Other option I have is to learn some object detection in python, train a model to recognize pdf417, and use that to extract codes from a video stream and decode them.

I hope you can guide me to find a good solution.
Thanks.